# How do I point the mkdir to the Desktop using bin/zsh? I am on macOS $HOME

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, script, zsh

How do I make this create the directory on my Mac desktop rather than the home folder alone.

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/${digits}_${date}"
```

Right now it goes to `/Users/name/`

I need it to go one more folder to the Desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your home directory, which is identified by the `HOME` shell variable (automatically set), you will find several sub-directories like `Documents`, `Downloads`, `Desktop`, etc.

To create a directory on your Desktop, you can change directory (`cd`) into the Desktop folder and use the make directory (`mkdir`) command (we are assuming the two variables `digits` and `date` have valid values already):

```
% cd $HOME/Desktop
% mkdir ${digits}_${date}
```

You could use [tilde (`~`) expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html#) to avoid expanding the `HOME` variable:

```
% cd ~/Desktop
```

And you could create the directory using a one-liner:

```
% mkdir $HOME/Desktop/${digits}_${date}

--or--

% mkdir ~/Desktop/${digits}_${date}
```

---

A note on variables and [variable/parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).  Shell variables are referenced by name (i.e. `HOME`) and not that there is a dollar sign (`$`) preceding it.  The `$` expands (or substitutes) the value the variable contains.

Example:

```
% myVAR="Hello World!"

% echo $myVAR    ← This is equivalent to 'echo Hello World!'
Hello World!
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Any time!  don't forget to mark it as "accepted" so the system shows it has an answer that worked.

Comment: Might be worth noting that HOME is set automatically by the shell and should/must not be set manually.